# Filter array by object property values

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am programming a function that will handle javascript array filtering. I know the values by which I want to filter so I know how to do it in a fairly easy way, but I would like the code to be more extensible.

I wrote such a function:

```
 const items = [
{
    prop1: 'Jotahan',
    prop2: 'London',
    prop3: '1234567'
},
{
    prop1: 'Jones',
    prop2: 'Paris',
    prop3: '987'
}
];

const filters = { prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987' };

   const handleFilters = (items, filters) => {
        return items.filter((item) => {
            if (filters.prop3 && filters.prop2) {
                return item.prop3 === filters.prop3 && item.prop2 === filters.prop2;
            }

            if (filters.prop3) {
                return item.prop3 === filters.prop3;
            }

            if (filters.prop2) {
                return item.prop2 === filters.prop2;
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not completely satisfied with it. I think it could be written better. If the 3rd argument comes, I don't want to add it to the if - it should be automatic.

I've searched several topics on stackoverflow, looked through the lodash documentation looking for some good solution but I have no idea what I can do better with this.

Comment: Can you give full code? With items example

Comment: Those `if (propX) { ... }` cases are no-ops. What are they supposed to do?

Comment: Your filter should return true if prop1 AND prop2 are equals or only if one of them is equal (OR)?

Comment: I updated the example.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to only keep the items that match all the filter:

```js
const items = [
    {
        prop1: 'Jotahan',
        prop2: 'London',
        prop3: '1234567'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'Jones',
        prop2: 'Paris',
        prop3: '987'
    }
];

const filters = {prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987'};

const handleFilters = (items, filters) => {
    return items.filter((item) =>
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, val]) => item[key] === val)
    )
};

console.log(handleFilters(items, filters))
```

This basically checks that every (key, val) of the filter exists in the item

Answer (score 0):

```
private handleFilters (items, ...props) {
    return items.filter(item => props.every(prop => item[prop] === prop));
}
```

Comment: every required type of Array value. In props value I have a object.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Mark, I'm not expect of upvotes. :) I send the trivial answer on relatively trivial question. And usually developers haven't much time to explain every line in such case, it's not a rocket science I guess. But thank you for advice in any case.

Answer (score 0):

To use the filter object dynamically, you could look into using something like `Object.keys()`.

Here's your example code changed to use that:

```
const items = [
    {
        prop1: 'Jotahan',
        prop2: 'London',
        prop3: '1234567'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'Jones',
        prop2: 'Paris',
        prop3: '987'
    }
];

const filters = { prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987' };

const handleFilters = (items, filters) => {
    return items.filter(item => {
        return Object.keys(filters).some(filterKey => item[filterKey] === filters[filterKey])
    });
}
```

It loops through the items, the same as you already were doing. However, now it also loops through the keys set in the `filters` object. The `some()` function returns a boolean; `true` if the callback is true and `false` if the callback is false. Here it checks if the value in `item[filterKey]` is the same as the value in `filters[filterKey]`.

It's important to note that this returns the item if any of the filter values matches with an item's property. If all values must be in the filtered item, you'll want to use `Object.keys(filters).every(filterKey => item[filterKey] === filters[filterKey])`.
The `every` function returns true only if all filterKeys have the same value as the keys checked in `item`.

It is also possible to use `Object.entries()`, which allows directly using the value, but for this example I chose to use just the keys, for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your multiple if blocks by using `for..in`

```js
const items = [
{
    prop1: 'Jotahan',
    prop2: 'London',
    prop3: '1234567'
},
{
    prop1: 'Jones',
    prop2: 'Paris',
    prop3: '987'
}
];

const filters = { prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987' };

   const handleFilters = (items, filters) => {
        return items.filter((item) => {
            for(const key in filters) {
                if (filters[key] !== item[key]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
    
console.log(handleFilters(items, filters))
```

It does the same as your code was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by using **Object.key** , **filter** and **every** method in precise manner.

```
const items = [
      {
        prop1: 'Jotahan',
        prop2: 'London',
        prop3: '1234567'
      },
      {
        prop1: 'Jones',
        prop2: 'Paris',
        prop3: '987'
      }
    ];
    
    const filters = { prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987' };
    
    const handleFilter = (items, filters) => {
      return items.filter((item) => Object.keys(filters).every((key) => item[key] === filters[key]));
    }
    
    console.log(handleFilter(items, filters))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Improvement over @David Alvarez approach, here i have used Object.keys instead of Object.entries as Object.key is faster than Object.entries here is the comparison: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/3685/0/objectentries-vs-objectkeys-vs-objectkeys-with-extra-ar

```js
const items = [
    {
        prop1: 'Jotahan',
        prop2: 'London',
        prop3: '1234567'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'Jones',
        prop2: 'Paris',
        prop3: '987'
    }
];

const filters = {prop2: 'Paris', prop3: '987'};

const handleFilters = (items, filters) => (
    items.filter((item) =>
        Object.keys(filters).every(key => item[key] === filters[key])
    )
);

console.log(handleFilters(items, filters))
```